# Elastic search's Logstash Mutate Split is not working

Tags: split, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I'm having trouble splitting the string type field(target) in logstash.

```
"log" => {
"address"  =>  "0.0.0.1",
"target" => "hello.exe - PID: 3005 - Module: nthdll.dll"
}
```

I try to divide by "-" and this is my code :

```
mutate {
  copy => { "[log][target]" => "targetList" }
  split => { "targetList" =>  "-" }
}
```

but it is not working,
"targetList" is copied, but the splits are not working.

```
"targetList" => "hello.exe - PID: 3005 - Module: nthdll.dll"
```

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mutate does operations in a [fixed order](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-proc_order), and split comes before copy, so the targetList field does not exist at the point when the split runs. Split it into two mutates

```
mutate { copy => { "[log][target]" => "targetList" } } 
mutate { split => { "targetList" =>  "-" } }
```

Please tag this as answering your problem if it solves your problem.